# One component affecting another in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Every url loads three main components: Left panel, center and right panel. In right panel, we have a button which returns a sub-component CreateForm inside the right panel. Left panel contains links which returns individual sub-component to left panel.

Here, the problem is every sub-component of the left panel changes url and thus loads three main components; so if current state of form is open on the right panel and if we select any links in the left panel sub-component, we get the right panel reloaded again so we cannot stay to form.

How can I solve that ?

Comment: I think, you need react router in your app

Comment: I am using it. It is just because of rightpanel component which is called again inside the subcomponent when we select it.

Comment: hey there @Urvashi-98 how about checking this out i tried to replicate what your saying but it is difficult to do so when I dont see what your code looks like so maybe you can upload some code any ways here is a like to a sandbox i created for you https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-rgb-p9onrw?file=/src/App.js 

Let me know is this what your trying to do ?

Comment: @kodamace yes, exactly. We are using react-router 6 npm we are using with browser router tag. Left, centre and right sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had use useEffect, localstorage for storing state of the contact form and do form component code inside rightpanel component only(without calling separate component for form on click). This worked well.